# When I replace a .so file used by a running PostgreSQL server it crashes

Tags: c, postgresql, unix, installation, mmap

I'm running PostgreSQL 9.2.8 on CentOS 5.8.

Building my own contrib module, I found that simply Changing `extension_name.so` file through `cp` makes the server process crashed but refreshing `extension_name.so` file through `make && make install` works properly.

This looks serious because the server process crashing leads to unexpected restarting of the cluster.

This is exactly same as `pg_stat_statements` and `pg_buffers` according to my own test.

Why is this happened? thanks.

Comment: Did you look to see what `make install` does? Seems like a really logical next step to me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### What's the difference?

`make install` typically uses the `install` command, which *deletes* then *re-creates* the file. (This isn't inherently true, it's just how most people's `Makefile`s are written).

By contrast, `cp` just overwrites it in place.

### Why does it matter?

UNIX/Linux systems `mmap` binaries into memory when they run. This means that the file contents are essentially directly part of the program memory. So when you overwrite the contents of an executable binary file while the program is running, things are likely to go *boom* in exciting ways.

By contrast, if you delete (unlink) the file, it remains mapped as an anonymous file. It still exists until the last handle to it is closed, it just doesn't have a file name anymore. The new file is then created with the same file name, but without affecting the contents of the now inaccessible unlinked file. So nothing crashes - so long as you don't have multiple instances of programs that expect to see the same version of a shared library, at least.

### How to do it right?

If you insist on replacing binaries of running executables, you should do so using the `install` command, or with `rm /the/path && cp /new/file /the/path` followed by any required `chown` and `chmod`.

### Demo showing the difference

Setup:

```
$ echo "whatevs" > blah
$ touch /tmp/blah
```

Using `install`:

```
strace -e unlink,open,write install blah /tmp/blah
...
unlink("/tmp/blah")                     = 0
open("blah", O_RDONLY)                  = 3
open("/tmp/blah", O_WRONLY|O_CREAT|O_EXCL, 0600) = 4
write(4, "whatevs\n", 8)                = 8
...
```

vs `cp`:

```
$ strace -e unlink,open,write cp blah /tmp/blah
...
open("blah", O_RDONLY)                  = 3
open("/tmp/blah", O_WRONLY|O_TRUNC)     = 4
write(4, "whatevs\n", 8)                = 8
...
```

Note how `install` `unlink`s the old file first? Crucial, that.

Another difference is that `install` won't change the contents of other links to the same underlying file, if a file has multiple hardlinks. `cp` will.